# Table of Content numbering (manual and variative)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I am interested to make my table of contents as described below, I am not sure whether it is possible or not... Please help me asap!
I shall be thankful.

Content

1. Chapter

   1.1 Section

   1.1.1 Subsection

   ```
     i. subsubsection
     ii. subsubsection
     iii. subsubsection
   ```

   1.1.2 Subsection

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  have you tried something already?  please show it to us, in the form of a compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  then we don't have to guess what you are working with, and can provide appropriate suggestions.

Comment: I am looking for a command that changes the numbering style as desired.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, mentioned below is the command used to re-define the numbering style for sections subsections and to further depth as desired. Using this command, I have changed the subsubsection numbering to roman, as asked in sample question.

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\roman{subsubsection}}

Comment: This will change the display of the numbers not only in the ToC but in the document as well -- you would have multiple `i.` , `ii` and `iii` etc. in every subsection which is especially quite confusing in the very end if you try to label them and refer them: There would be many references with the same number -- which one is the correct then?

Comment: Yes, That's true...
It will not be confusion (may be not for me) as for my document I have very few and I need to display them in contents also, and in content 1.1.1.1 looks very strange so after  each subsection it will be roman numbering for simplicity.
As far document is concerned nothing is referred for the subsection so no problem....
If you want to refer them, then the normal numbering is best option.

Comment: In case you want to refer them, you may change the command structure as mentioned below for numbering to be done as,
section.nr.-subsubsection.nr. but again each subsection has different subsubsections....
so, in case of refering them, one must always follow the general numbering.
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection--\roman{subsubsection}}